# CoffeeScript Indent Error

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Any idea why this would throw an error when compiling?

```
(window) ->

    # pubsub
    App.publish = (topic,args) ->
        App.subscriptions[topic] and $.each(App.subscriptions[topic], ->
            this.apply(App, args or [])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wesbos/4Kf2B/

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I'm silly and forgot a remove paren :\

(window) ->

```
# pubsub
App.publish = (topic,args) ->
    App.subscriptions[topic] and $.each App.subscriptions[topic], ->
        this.apply(App, args or [])
```